# How to render 3D shape with transparency using GLKit in iOS

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios5, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I have some 3D shape defined by set of Vertices/normal/indices. I wish to render some object with semi-transperency. Some objects have textures and some do not.

I am using GLKit for the development on iOS. Kindly tell how can I achieve the effect?

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment shader simply set the `gl_Fragcolor` to a colour with an alpha value of less than 1.